# Regular expression to add a word in a variable position in certain sentences

Tags: python, regex

I have an embarrassingly rookie question, but I think I'm stuck and can't think straight.

I want a regular expression pattern that will add the word `'old'` after the word `'year'` or `'years'`, only if the word `'child'` or `'children'` is also present in the sentence (a pattern I detected in my data).

So:

*'Especially in children who are one year or up to twelve years old, for seven years.'*

will have 'old' added after the fist 'year', but not an extra one added after the second old, and also not after the two final words:

*'Especially in children who are one year **old** or up tp twelve years old, for seven years.'*

My patterns so far have managed to all be wrong, e.g.,

```
if 'child' or 'children' in i.split() and 'old' or 'olds' not in  i.split(): 
    i=re.sub(r'year' ,'year old',i)
```

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See analysis on regex101 for explanation: https://regex101.com/r/hTsPlF/1.

```
import re
i = 'Especially in children who are one year or up to twelve years old, for seven years.'
if re.search(r'(\bchild\b)|(\bchildren\b)',i):
    re.sub('(years{0,1}) (?!old)',r'\1 old ',i)
```

Which gives:

```
'Especially in children who are one year old or up to twelve years old, for seven years.'
```

Comment: Same i solution i thought. +1

Comment: I see.. Much simpler than I thought, as usual. Great, many thanks, I'll play around with it.

Comment: On side note:- it's better to use `?` instead of `{0,1}`, and the `(\bchild\b)|(\bchildren\b)` can be reduced to `\b(?:child(?:ren)?)\b`

Comment: @CodeManiac Thanks